# Tensorflow gather and uninformative weight updating (tensorflow-Python)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm building a simple model in TensorFlow (v 2.1) and am running into some strange behavior with `tf.gather` -- It's possible that I don't understand what it does.

I'm considering a model that could have multiple intercepts (i.e. `y = a[i] + X@b`). I define a new layer, as shown below,

```py
class GroupedInterceptLinearCoeffs_gather(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    """
    """
    def __init__(self, ngroup=1, **kwargs):
        super(GroupedInterceptLinearCoeffs_gather, self).__init__()
        self.ngroup = ngroup

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.a = self.add_weight(
            shape=(self.ngroup,), dtype="float32",
            initializer="random_normal", trainable=True
        )
        self.b = self.add_weight(
            shape=(input_shape[1][-1],), dtype="float32",
            initializer="random_normal", trainable=True
        )

    @tf.function()
    def call(self, inputs):
        out = tf.gather(self.a, inputs[0], axis=0, batch_dims=0) + tf.linalg.matvec(inputs[1], self.b)
        return out
```

And then check that it does what I expect with

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

nobs = 100

alpha = 1.0  # To keep things simple, we'll only have one intercept here
beta = np.array([0.0, 0.5, 0.25])
L = np.array([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.25, 1.1, 0.0], [0.2, 0.2, 1.25]])
X = np.random.randn(nobs, 3) @ L

y = alpha + X@beta
```

Checking whether the model can reproduce my data shows that there is (effectively) 0 error

```py
gilc_g = GroupedInterceptLinearCoeffs_gather(ngroup=1)

gilc_g([np.zeros((X.shape[0],), dtype=np.int32), X.astype(np.float32)])

gilc_g.set_weights([np.array([alpha], dtype=np.float32), beta.astype(np.float32)])

np.max(
    np.abs(
        gilc_g(
            [np.zeros((X.shape[0],), dtype=np.int32), X.astype(np.float32)]
        ).numpy() - (alpha + X@beta)
    )
)
```

but when I try and fit a model to it, it quickly stops making progress.

```py
class OLS_gather(tf.keras.Model):
    """
    """
    def __init__(self, ngroups=1, name="ols", **kwargs):
        super(OLS_gather, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.lm = GroupedInterceptLinearCoeffs_gather(ngroups)

    def call(self, inputs):
        print(inputs[0].shape)
        print(inputs[1].shape)
        out = self.lm(inputs)

        return out


olsmodel_g = OLS_gather(ngroups=1)

olsmodel_g.compile(optimizer, loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())
olsmodel_g.fit([np.zeros((X.shape[0],), dtype=np.int32), X.astype(np.float32)], y.astype(np.float32), epochs=50)
```

Inspecting the `b` weights shows that it is not moving the weights in the right direction, but a similar model (without the gather) quickly converges (see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/cc7768/5982deff13638b827e857569933efb96) for all of the code). Am I using `tf.gather` incorrectly? If so, is there another way to "reindex" an array like that to generate duplicates in a particular order?

(Also, I know that I don't necessarily need to be building my own layers/models but my actual example is a bit more complicated and I need a custom loss function etc...)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the behavior you described, my guess is that using `tf.gather` to dynamically use weights somehow interferes with model learning.

You could avoid using `tf.gather` altogether and instead use a one-hot encoding with `tf.one_hot` and simple multiplication to select which intercept to use.

The code below was successful for a model with two intercepts where the input data always selects the first one:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

nobs = 100

alpha = 1.0
beta = np.array([0.0, 0.5, 0.25])
L = np.array([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.25, 1.1, 0.0], [0.2, 0.2, 1.25]])
X = np.random.randn(nobs, 3) @ L

y = alpha + X@beta

class GroupedInterceptLinearCoeffs_gather(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    """"""
    def __init__(self, ngroup=2, **kwargs):
        super(GroupedInterceptLinearCoeffs_gather, self).__init__()
        self.ngroup = ngroup

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.a = self.add_weight(
            shape=(self.ngroup,), dtype="float32",
            initializer="random_normal", trainable=True
        )
        self.b = self.add_weight(
            shape=(input_shape[1][-1],), dtype="float32",
            initializer="random_normal", trainable=True
        )

    @tf.function()
    def call(self, inputs):
        out = tf.linalg.matvec(inputs[0], self.a) \
            + tf.linalg.matvec(inputs[1], self.b)
        return out

class OLS_gather(tf.keras.Model):
    """"""
    def __init__(self, ngroups=1, name="ols", **kwargs):
        super(OLS_gather, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.lm = GroupedInterceptLinearCoeffs_gather(ngroups)

    def call(self, inputs):
        out = self.lm(inputs)

        return out

olsmodel_g = OLS_gather(ngroups=2)
optimizer_g = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-2)
olsmodel_g.compile(optimizer_g, loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())

x = [tf.cast(tf.one_hot(np.zeros((X.shape[0],), dtype=np.int32), depth=2), tf.float32),
     tf.constant(X)]
y = tf.constant(y)

olsmodel_g.fit(x=x, y=y,
    epochs=25, batch_size=25, verbose=False
)

print(olsmodel_g.trainable_weights)

olsmodel_g.fit(x=x, y=y,
    epochs=1, batch_size=25
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This is very helpful for this particular case -- Another friend (that I trust) recommended the same thing when I showed them this example! My actual use case of `gather` is a bit more complicated and, while I could probably write it as a one hot encoding, it isn't immediately obvious how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @spencerlyon2, I think we have a better idea of what's happening.

The issue seems to be that when a 1-D array is passed as an input to tensorflow, they automatically convert it to a 2-D array when standardizing inputs (see, [these lines of code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/10666c59dd4858645d1b03ce01f4450da80710ec/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py#L439-L457)). This creates shape inconsistencies and, rather than throw an error (?), it seems to fail silently when fitting and not update the parameters correctly.

One brute force way to fix this would be to simply squeeze the first input in the `call` method of `GroupedInterceptLinearCoeffs_gather`.